# APK file missing

Tags: android, android-manifest

I was creating a simple android application on sudoku.
One day i found that my APK file was missing.
Is there anyway to restore it by any means?
I have tried "retore from local history","changing the dependencies and all possible solutions that I could find from all the blogs but no use.
Can anyone suggest a solution for this.
When I went through my logcat the only error that I could find was "No activity found to handle intent{act=org.example.sudoku.about}

Here is my manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="org.example.sudoku"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
     >
    <activity
        android:name="org.example.sudoku.Sudoku"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="org.example.sudoku.About"
        android:label="@string/about_title"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">


    <action android:name=".prefs" 
           android:label="@string/settings_title" />

    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

This is my about.java and about.xml files
    about.java

```
package org.example.sudoku;

import org.example.sudoku.R;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class About extends Activity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.about);
}
}
```

about.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView 
    android:id="@+id/about_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/about_text"/>

</ScrollView>
```

Logcat:

```
06-01 07:44:46.890: E/AndroidRuntime(930): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=org.example.sudoku.About }
06-01 07:44:46.890: E/AndroidRuntime(930):  at org.example.sudoku.Sudoku.onClick(Sudoku.java:36)
```

Answer (score 0):

Check in your SDK Manager if Build Tools is updated.

Comment: Remove this import and rebuild 
import org.example.sudoku.R;

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure .But I think that you may have to remove the following Import.

```
import org.example.sudoku.R;
```

Then,Run again.

Comment: I am sorry..That will create an error in xml files and your R.java file will be missing..thats not the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try to rebuild your apk again maybe its helps.
Go to menu in android studio search for "Build" and then "BUILD APk(s)".
It will create an apk file again